# Android - Bring scroll view above fixed button

Tags: android, android-studio

following is what my Job Info user interface looks like:

[image]

As the user scrolls across the screen, I want all the text to show up above the fixed button "Request For Hire". Right now the text is being covered by the button.This is my XML. I tried a few things I found online, but I'm not getting what I need. How will I do this?

**activity_job_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".JobInfo">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/HeaderStyle"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Find Your Next Gig"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menuIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
            android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:queryHint="Search Jobs"
            android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_magnifying_glass"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:theme="@style/Search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_burger_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_noun_filter" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="358dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobName_info"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recruiterName_info"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobName_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobLocation_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recruiterName_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobCharge_info"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/jobLocation_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recruiterName_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobDate_info"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobCharge_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobTime_info"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDate_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobDesc_header"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Job Description"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prof_pic_info" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobTasks_header"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Your Tasks"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/additonalPref_header"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Additional Preferences"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobTasks"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks_header" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/additionalPref"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additonalPref_header" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jobDesc"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc_header" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/request_hire_container"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Request For Hire"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#272343"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/hamburger_menu"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_drawer"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemHorizontalPadding="30dp"
        app:itemIconSize="16dp"
        app:itemIconTint="#272343"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Nav_text"
        app:menu="@menu/hamburger_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Constraint the ScrollView bottom to Button's top constraint.
2. Then set android:layout_height="0dp" of the scrollView

I have made changes in your code, copy-paste whole code and try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".JobInfo">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/HeaderStyle"
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
    android:text="Find Your Next Gig"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menuIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
    android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    android:queryHint="Search Jobs"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_magnifying_glass"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:theme="@style/Search" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_burger_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_noun_filter" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobName_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recruiterName_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobName_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobLocation_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recruiterName_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobCharge_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/jobLocation_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recruiterName_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDate_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobCharge_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTime_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prof_pic_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDate_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDesc_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Job Description"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prof_pic_info" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTasks_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Your Tasks"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additonalPref_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Additional Preferences"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobTasks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobTasks_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/additionalPref"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additonalPref_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jobDesc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jobDesc_header" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/request_hire_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="Request For Hire"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#272343"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/hamburger_menu"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_drawer"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
app:itemHorizontalPadding="30dp"
app:itemIconSize="16dp"
app:itemIconTint="#272343"
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Nav_text"
app:menu="@menu/hamburger_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You're welcome... The changes made are written on top lines of the answer, do check.